# Obj-C, CLS_LOG Crashlytics logging not showing debug output in the Xcode console?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, crashlytics

I have two apps written using Objective C and both use Crashlytics.

I'm using the latest version of Crashlytics via Cocoapods.

From what I can see both apps have an identical setup.

However one app shows the CLS_LOG debugging in the Xcode console and one doesn't, I can't figure out why it doesn't show in the other app.

I've followed the steps highlighted in the documentation to no avail.

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Can you share the output from a run of both? I'd like to see if there are any startup logs around Crashlytics that are different.

Comment: I don't see anything from one app, is there anywhere I can get further logging? thanks.

Comment: Try using debug mode - https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html?highlight=debug - or log the same values to NSLog and see if they come through in both cases.

Comment: I did try the debug mode and still nothing was coming through, I'll try NSLog and report back, thanks

Comment: Although I did have debug mode set after "Fabric with"

Comment: Thanks, I have OS_ACTIVITY_MODE set to disable, working now :)

Comment: You should post that as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` set to `disabled` in my scheme

Comment: set to `default` to show the debug messages. Add these lines to show additional debug information: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html?highlight=debug